# Pulling Data from an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

So I have an NSDictionary that has a variety of data within it. When printed to the log, it prints like this:

```
[{"user_id":3016817,"grade":"A","percent":"93","grading_periods":[{"assignments":[{"points":100.0,"grade":"A","score":95.0,"percent":"93","comment":null,"id":3268180},{"points":100.0,"grade":"A","score":90.0,"percent":"93","comment":null,"id":3268181}],"grade":"A","percent":"93","name":"Default"}]},{"user_id":3016818,"grade":"A","percent":"94","grading_periods":[{"assignments":[{"points":100.0,"grade":"A","score":92.0,"percent":"94","comment":null,"id":3268180},{"points":100.0,"grade":"A","score":95.0,"percent":"94","comment":null,"id":3268181}],"grade":"A","percent":"94","name":"Default"}]}]
```

If I use a formatter online, its a lot more readable and looks something like this:

```
[
{
    "user_id": 3016817, 
    "grade": "A", 
    "percent": "93", 
    "grading_periods": [
        {
            "assignments": [
                {
                    "points": 100, 
                    "grade": "A", 
                    "score": 95, 
                    "percent": "93", 
                    "comment": null, 
                    "id": 3268180
                }, 
                {
                    "points": 100, 
                    "grade": "A", 
                    "score": 90, 
                    "percent": "93", 
                    "comment": null, 
                    "id": 3268181
                }
            ], 
            "grade": "A", 
            "percent": "93", 
            "name": "Default"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "user_id": 3016818, 
    "grade": "A", 
    "percent": "94", 
    "grading_periods": [
        {
            "assignments": [
                {
                    "points": 100, 
                    "grade": "A", 
                    "score": 92, 
                    "percent": "94", 
                    "comment": null, 
                    "id": 3268180
                }, 
                {
                    "points": 100, 
                    "grade": "A", 
                    "score": 95, 
                    "percent": "94", 
                    "comment": null, 
                    "id": 3268181
                }
            ], 
            "grade": "A", 
            "percent": "94", 
            "name": "Default"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

My question would be how would I access the value of grade or score for a specific user_id using this dictionary?

Comment: It's not a dictionary. It's an array of dictionaries. There is a big difference!

Comment: If this is JSON, any reason you're not using NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Oh ok! How would this affect how I would access the data? Im curious because all of this is in one NSDictionary variable.

Comment: You may have _called_ it an NSDictionary variable when you declared it, but that doesn't make it an NSDictionary. Lying to the compiler will only lead to a crash later when you try to treat it as an NSDictionary and it isn't one. It is an NSArray. Trust me on this one.

Comment: OK I see, i changed it from an NSDictionary to an NSArray which allows me to use the objectAtIndex function which will then allow me to select which set of data to use. Now how would I pull the specific dictionary with, say, the user_id equal to 3016818?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string represents a `NSArray`, not a `NSDictionary`. And it's a JSON string, so you can parse it using `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"..." // your string here

// Create array from json string
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
    JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                 error:Nil];

// Loop to find your user_id
// Because each child of this array is a dictionary
for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
    if ([dic[@"user_id"] isEqual:@3016817]) { // user_id field is number
        // Access what you want
        NSString *grade = dic[@"grade"];

        // For "score" you must go deeper
        // Just remember, [] is array and {} is dictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: I see now! I wasn't using the dic[@"grade"] part within the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be

```
for (NSDictionary* d in theArray) {
    if ([d[@"user_id"] isEqualToString: u]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And matt is right, it is an array of dictionaries, no matter what type you declared to be.

Comment: This causes the app to crash when I change theArray to the array of dictionaries and set "u" to a user_id that I know exists.

Comment: it because `user_id` field is number, not string. You can compare it using `isEqual:u`, with `u` is a `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below class method of NSJsonSerialization class to create NSArray which will contain all the dictionaries.

+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error;

Once you get the array of dictionaries from JSON, you can do following:

```
NSArray *filteredjsonArr = [jsonArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id == %@", @"3016818"]];
NSDictionary *dict = [filtered firstObject];
if (dict != nil) {
   NSString *grade = [dict objectForKey:@"grade"];
   NSArray *gradingPeriods = [dict objectForKey:@"grading_periods"];
}
```

To access score and grade for specific assignments, you'll need to drill down further into gradingPeriods array.